# Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-headers, httpresponse

I get this exception intermittently in my asp.net c# web application:

Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent.

And it caused by the application appending content to the pages response header after the page has been sent. I am not sure why its intermittent but what I need to do is perform a check prior to the modification for the headers to check if the page has been sent.

Anyone know how I can achieve such a check?

Comment: I get the same error when calling some pages that have Response.BufferOutput = false. Removing that resolve the issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do it:

1. Subscribe to the `PreSendRequestHeaders` of `HttpApplication` and assume that the headers have been sent at this point. Set a flag on the context and check for it everywhere
2. The ugly solution:
   `HttpResponse` has a internal property called `HeadersWritten`. Since it's internal you'll have to access it through reflection. I'd recommand only to use this for debugging. Check it before/after all the page lifecyle events and find out where the problem is. Don't leave this in production code

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think option 1 is best. Is this the last point at which cookies and http headers can be set in the http response?

Comment: as the name of the event says it happens right before the headers are sent. It's the latest time at which you can still set headers

Comment: is there an example to how this is implemented for Step 1? Like it'll be good