# .NET 'Set a flag in the context'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, http

I have an issue similar to this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328437/server-cannot-append-header-after-http-headers-have-been-sent). Looking at the answer, I had to do a little bit of reading to understand about how you can add methods to events in .NET. The only part of that answer I still don't understand is where it says to 'set a flag in the context'. Is it referring to the HttpContext object? Is there a variable there I can set and check? Can anyone clarify this?

Comment: Please make your question complete - inline whatever you think related from linked question/answers/your reading into this question. It is hard to understand the question in current form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's referring to the context which subscribes to the event. The one that cares about whether a send has occurred or not.

Comment: Ah, got it, thought it meant something beyond that, guess not.